# File streaming on HTTPS is slow

Tags: java, performance, https, streaming

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{

   protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   {

       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

       request.ReadWriteTimeout = 2147483647;

       request.Timeout = 2147483647;

       request.SendChunked = true;

       request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
       request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
       // request.exnc = Encoding.UTF8;

       return request;

   }

}

WebClientEx wc = new WebClientEx();

                  wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(@"https://www.exmaple.com/API/FileOperations/UploadFile.svc/UploadFileStream"), "POST", file);
```

My problem is with HTTPS in URL, the file streaming is dead slow. Where as with HTTP its very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that HTTPS is a secure (meaning encrypted) socket, whereas HTTP is an unencrypted connection. Depending on what HTTPS encryption algorithm is used, it can decrease performance in the transfer of files. This is caused by the need to encrypt and decrypt all traffic between the client and server. If you have a large file, it will take quite a long time for the data to be transferred to be encrypted on one side, then decrypted on the other side. There is also the need for a key generation and exchange with a secured socket, although this is not the main cause of decrease in performance.

Further reading: How encryption can affect performance (https://superuser.com/questions/173588/data-encryption-and-internet-speed).

Final notes: If you are looking at transferring an encrypted file, try using SFTP (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html).

Comment: I can compromise for slight delay in performance but not to such a huge extent. Any solution for this?